# How to set MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT with JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have a class annotated with JPA:

```
@Entity
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Min(1000000)
    private Long id;

    private Cart() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Using auto DDL this results in a MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `cart` (
    `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;
```

But I want the `AUTO_INCREMENT` to have value `1000000` after DB creation.

How can this be achieved using JPA?

Kind regards

Stefaan

Comment: Also if you are using a mysql server, you should probably install MS Workbench, you could right click a table, select ALTER, and then go to town clicking the check boxes to define your primary key as Auto Increment and all that .   Not sure how often you have to alter a table, but if its more than once a day, this program will save you much time.

Comment: I'll offer a counter-argument. MySQL Workbench is full of bugs and performance problems. I have used MySQL for 20+ years, but I never use the GUI. I don't think it saves any time to use the GUI, if you count all the time troubleshooting why it isn't working. I use MySQL from the command-line, SQL scripts, or else I write a quick Python script to do some tasks.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved via @TableGenerator Annotation, if given annotation supported by JPA Provider.

TableGenerator Annotation will create new table there it will keep initial default value as provided and query should be like this.

Hibernate:

```
create table cart (
   id bigint not null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

Hibernate:

```
create table cart_id_generator (
   pk_name varchar(255) not null,
    pk_value bigint,
    primary key (pk_name)
)
```

Hibernate:

```
insert into cart_id_generator(pk_name, pk_value) values ('cart',1000000)


@Entity
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "cart_id_generator", table = "cart_id_generator", pkColumnName = "pk_name", valueColumnName = "pk_value", initialValue = 1000000)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "cart_id_generator")
    private Long id;

    private Cart() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```